# How to produce a bilingual tagged-PDF output from Jaspersoft / JRXML?

Tags: jasper-reports, multilingual, export-to-pdf, tagged-pdf

We're using Jaspersoft iReport Designer to create bilingual PDF outputs—each file contains both English and French text.

For accessibility reasons, we'd like to tag each block of text with its appropriate language in the resulting PDF. See [PDF19: Specifying the language for a passage or phrase with the Lang entry in PDF documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF19.html) for what we're trying to do.

Modifying the PDF files manually is not an option since we email them directly to our users.

Does Jaspersoft support this?

Comment: You can look at [net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language) property and other *net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.** properties

Comment: Thanks Alex! That property defines the language for the document (Global | Context | Report scope). I'm looking for something similar but with element scope.

Comment: It may be possible to [use iText](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/working-with-marked-content-itext-5/) to change an element's language. I don't know if this is possible with iText 2 (ships with JasperReports under a special license).

Comment: Currently on Jaspersoft iReport Designer v4.1.2 but would be open to changing versions if it would make this possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No JasperReports version<=6.7.0 do **not** support this, there is no available property in [Configuration Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html) to set `Lang` property to single textElement.

You have 2 options:

1. Post elaborate the pdf with for example iText as Dave Jarvis [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253604/producing-bilingual-tagged-pdf-output-from-jaspersoft-jrxml#comment89633493_51253604). You can either try to change the dictionary or recreate the pdf adding this additional info. These methods are both fairly complex and naturally runtime will increase since you will need to read/recreate the pdf.
2. Modify [source code](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/tree/master/jasperreports) of JasperReport to add support. Directly modify the JRPdfExporter, JRPdfExporterTagHelper or add your new exporter (to keep original library intact)

In this answer I will show you how you can modify the original lib adding additional tags (adding a LANG entry in the dictionary)

## Background

The [example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/working-examples/PDF19/lang-of-phrase.pdf) in [PDF19: Specifying the language for a passage or phrase with the Lang entry in PDF documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF19.html), show this PDF Object tree using iText RUPS.

[image: example1]

I will assume that it is sufficient to add `/Lang` in our output related to the specific text that is not in default language of pdf. Note: If you need to add other entry as well the technique remains the same you just need to modify the below code example.

## Source code modification

> Add a new property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.lang` if this
>   is present on reportElement in a type text field add a `/Lang` entry
>   with its value to dictionary.

Modification to [JRPdfExporterTagHelper.java](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/89055a52f85c589ff08f0a72d0108ecf17a388e6/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterTagHelper.java)

**Add static property  identifier to follow code style**

```
public static final String PROPERTY_TAG_LANG = JRPdfExporter.PDF_EXPORTER_PROPERTIES_PREFIX + "tag.lang";
```

**Modify [`startText(boolean isHyperLink)`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/89055a52f85c589ff08f0a72d0108ecf17a388e6/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterTagHelper.java#L569) and [`startText(String text, boolean isHyperlink)`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/89055a52f85c589ff08f0a72d0108ecf17a388e6/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterTagHelper.java#L580)**, only first method is shown in this example (principal is same in second), we need to change method signature adding `JRPrintText` so that we can retrive properties.

```
protected void startText(JRPrintText text, boolean isHyperlink)
    {
        if (isTagged)
        {

            PdfStructureElement textTag = new PdfStructureElement(tagStack.peek(), isHyperlink ? PdfName.LINK : PdfName.TEXT);
            if (text.hasProperties()&&text.getPropertiesMap().containsProperty(PROPERTY_TAG_LANG)){
                textTag.put(PdfName.LANG, new PdfString(text.getPropertiesMap().getProperty(PROPERTY_TAG_LANG)));
            }
            pdfContentByte.beginMarkedContentSequence(textTag);
        }
    }
```

Since we change method signature we now need to modify [JRPdfExporter.java](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/89055a52f85c589ff08f0a72d0108ecf17a388e6/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.java) so that we can recompile

**Modify [`exportText(JRPrintText text)`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/89055a52f85c589ff08f0a72d0108ecf17a388e6/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.java#L2443)**

```
...
if (glyphRendererAddActualText && textRenderer instanceof PdfGlyphRenderer)
{
    tagHelper.startText(text,styledText.getText(), text.getLinkType() != null);
}
else
{
    tagHelper.startText(text,text.getLinkType() != null);
}
...
```

<sup>You could remove the boolean `text.getLinkType() != null`, since we are actually passing the text object now, but I wanted to keep similar code for simplicity of example</sup>

## Example

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TaggedPdf" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1be2df3d-cbc1-467c-8729-1ed569eb8a0d">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tagged" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language" value="EN-US"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="67" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="240" height="30" uuid="0722eadc-3fd6-4c4d-811c-64fbd18e0af5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Hello world]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="240" height="30" uuid="5080190e-e9fd-4df6-b0f6-f1be3c109805">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.lang" value="FR"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Bonjour monde]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Exported to pdf with modifications above and visualized with iText RUPS**

[image: Final output]

Is this enough according to *PDF19: Specifying the language for a passage or phrase with the Lang entry in PDF documents*

> Verify that the language of a passage, phrase, or word that differs from the language of the surrounding text is correctly specified by a /Lang entry on an enclosing tag or container:

As far as I can see, yes but I'm not an expert in this matter, in any case if you need to add other tags the procedure is the same.